# How are piled-up orders matched?

Tags: order-execution, order-handling

Suppose that the market is closed, but orders are queued up to be matched as soon as the market opens. Suppose for simplicity that only two orders are queued:

1. A sell order to sell 1 unit at \$1.00
2. A buy order to buy 1 unit at \$1.10

If order 1 came in before order 2, the orders are matched at \$1.00, and if order 2 came in before order 1, the orders are matched at \$1.10. But in this case both orders come in at exactly the same time, and hence I don't know what a natural price would be for this transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each exchange is a bit different, especially the listing exchange vs others, so no one answer. This should add a bit of color on the [Nasdaq opening auction](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/productsservices/trading/crosses/openclose_faqs.pdf) -

Comment: Thanks, also for the reference, very interesting that this sort of stuff is documented an publicly available.

Comment: @user2520938 why do you find it interesting that the exchange provides information on how it operates?

Answer (score 1):

If timestamps are the same, the orders will be processed based on order number, a unique identifier assigned by the exchange at the time each order is added to the queue.